# How to avoid back button generated by [navPush] (Handling generated back Button)

Tags: navigation, ionic2, back-button

I have a home page which is my first screen.

after i navigate to some pages On clicking a button i need to get back to the home page without back button

for navigation i use `[navPush]='pageName';`

This `navPush` automatically generates back button. But i dont need the back button when i go back.

I tried `navPop` it is working fine but the problem is it takes to the next page only .

**Example**

> if i have 10 pages from 10th page i have to come to 1st page using ionic `navPop` i am not able to achieve this .
>
> When i tried with navPush i am able to get back but i am not able to avoid the back button in homepage.

**Question:**

> Is there anything else i am missing how to avoid the back button generated using `navPush` or `navPop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On clicking a button I need to get back to the home page without back
>   button

Please take a look at this [working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vKgkOF?p=preview).

1. You can use the [setRoot() method](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/NavController/#setRoot) like this:

   ```
   this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
   ```
2. If you really need to use the `push` method instead of the `setRoot`, you can also try with the [showBackButton() method](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/ViewController/#showBackButton) from the `ViewController`

   > showBackButton(Set):  Set if the back button for the current view is
   >   visible or not. Be sure to call this after **ionViewWillEnter** to make
   >   sure the DOM has been rendered.